# android; returning to activity from intent.action_view results in weird overlay on view

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a view where the onClick launches a browser; simple enough. For some reason I cannot determine, when the user returns to the activity via the system back button, the original view has a weird overlay on it. It appears for a flash prior to the browser launching; there's nothing in the activity that's otherwise impacting it's view in response to this event, so I'm baffled as to what's going on. The code for the intent is totally straight forward:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Another possible important detail: the view that triggers this is inserted into the current activities view in response to handling an intent from a service. The current activity receives the intent, then processes the data and displays the view. It's during the processing of the intent that we setup the sub view that triggers the ACTION_VIEW intent by assigning it's onClick handler. I don't think that should make a difference, but it is a distinction none the less.

When returning to the app via the system back button, I see this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the action_view intent was fired inside a block of code that created a Dialog first, then hit the call to the web intent, which bypassed further setup on the dialog, and subsequently called show on the dialog, so it was the empty dialog still there upon return.